I'm able to see closed questions from the Staging Ground on the front page
Very rarely, I'm able to see posts from the Staging Ground on the front page where the question has been closed. If I'm not mistaken, closed questions shouldn't be appearing on the front page, so I'm guessing I shouldn't be able to see this?
It only happens very rarely, so I suspect it's some kind of race condition occurring.


Asked 42 seconds ago and already closed. That's efficient. And also probably why you see this, I am going to guess this is going to be another case of blameitoncaching.

@Gimby https://shouldiblamecaching.com/
